# HttpsURLConnection openConnection Query

Tags: java, sockets, networking, https, httpsurlconnection

I am using JAVA Class `HttpsURLConnection` to get content  from a HTTPS website.  I am using my own `SSLSocketFactory`.

Code snippet below:

```
 HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new java.net.URL("https", google.com, 443, "/").openConnection();

                conn.setHostnameVerifier(new hver());
                conn.setReadTimeout(0);
                conn.setSSLSocketFactory(my.sslSocketFactory);//mine
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.connect();
```

If you see first `createSocket(...)` method , `HttpsURLConnection`    itself creating a `Socket` object 'so'  and passing it as parameter.  Is there any way to create that 'so' object from my code . In other word , can I force  `HttpsURLConnection`    to call  other `createSocket()`  methods which are  accepting only host port as parameter.  I want to make initial socket object from my code only.

```
public class CustomSocketFactoty extends SSLSocketFactory {

    // method 1  
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(*Socket so*, String host, int port,
                               boolean autoClose) throws IOException {

        // HttpsURLConnection itself creating ( in parameter )socket object Socket so  and passing it here , Instead  I want to create that Socket object so from my code.
        // it is  called from - conn.connect();
        return ...;
    }



    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException,
            UnknownHostException {
             // This method never called
        return ...;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
     // This method never called
        return ...;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port,
                               InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
     // This method never called
        return ...;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port,
                               InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        // This method never called
        return ...;
    }


}
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to create the socket in your own code?

Comment: At which conditions other createSocket()  methods which are accepting only Host name and port  as parameter get invoked. Looks like they have no use for   HttpsURLConnection

Comment: You think you want this why?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with [`HttpsURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html). See this example:

http://rtfcode.com/xref/java-1.8/jdk/test/sun/security/ssl/sun/net/www/protocol/https/HttpsURLConnection/HttpsSocketFacTest.java#L168

You may want to check if the given socket is null in your createSocket implementation.

You could also use the Apache HTTP client. You can provide an implementation of [`SSLConnectionSocketFactory`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLConnectionSocketFactory.html) that overrides [`ConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/socket/ConnectionSocketFactory.html#connectSocket(int,%20java.net.Socket,%20org.apache.http.HttpHost,%20java.net.InetSocketAddress,%20java.net.InetSocketAddress,%20org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)). This creates the initial socket.

See the "Custom SSL context" example:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java

Comment: Thanks jspcal.  below method  allowing to create only a Unconnected Socket object. But it does not allow to make connection.    public Socket createSocket() throws ...
  {  return new Socket();   }

Comment: If I make connection and return Socket Object  it's giving error saying "SOCKET ALREADY CONNECTED"